# angular-ui-router conflict with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: SyntaxHighlighter is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:9000/assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:328:5), <anonymous>:2:9)
    at jQuery.Callbacks.fire (http://127.0.0.1:9000/assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3094:30)
    at Object.jQuery.Callbacks.self.add [as done] (http://127.0.0.1:9000/assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3140:7)
    at jQuery.fn.ready (http://127.0.0.1:9000/assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3373:25)
    at jQuery.fn.init (http://127.0.0.1:9000/assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2816:16)
    at jQuery (http://127.0.0.1:9000/assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:76:10)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:9000/assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:328:5), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at eval (native)
    at Function.jQuery.extend.globalEval (http://127.0.0.1:9000/assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:328:5)
    at jQuery.fn.extend.domManip (http://127.0.0.1:9000/assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5430:16) <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

I'm loading the jquery js file first and then the angular one. If I load the angular one first I do not get this error but some plugins that I use rely on jquery and they do not load. Has anyone encountered this before? As far as I understand the error is caused by angular ui router module.

Comment: Have you included the necessary reference in your `app.js` file for the Syntax  Highlighter package?

Comment: no, how do I do that ?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/pc035860/angular-highlightjs

Comment: I don't use any highlighter... when I load angular first it works by default... when I load jquery first I get that error

Comment: You're referring to SyntaxHighlighter somewhere in your code!